# Trying to fire a bullet and detect a rectangle for collision

Tags: java

I created an oval which shoots a bullet(rectangle) that if it hits the red rectangle, the collision would detect the bullet hitting the rectangle. However, when I run my program, the collision has already been done and I haven't even pressed the space bar yet to shoot. What I wanted to happen is that, when I shoot and if the bullet hits the rectangle, that's when it detects the collision. I tried to analyze it and do something but I just couldn't get it. here is my source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaGame2 extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable{

//variables
JFrame frame;
int x, y, xDir, yDir,bx,by;
Rectangle bullet;
boolean readyTofire, shot = false;


//constructor for game
public JavaGame2(){

    frame = new JFrame("Java Game");
    int x=150;
    int y=150;


}



//drawings
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 20, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 55, 55);
    g.fillRect(x+23, y-15, 10, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);
    bullet = new Rectangle(bx, by, 5, 3);


    if(shot){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height);
    }

    if(bullet.intersects(rec));
        g.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);

    repaint();

}

public void setxDir(int xdir){
    xDir = xdir;
}
public void setyDir(int ydir){
    yDir = ydir;
}



//key event listener keypressed

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        setyDir(-1);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        setyDir(+1);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        setxDir(-1);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        setxDir(+1);

     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        if(bullet == null ){

            readyTofire = true;
            if(readyTofire){
                bx = x+26;
                by = y-15;
                bullet = new Rectangle(bx, by, 5, 3);
                shot = true;


            }

        }
     }
}

//key event listener for key released
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        setyDir(0);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        setyDir(0);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        setxDir(0);
     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        setxDir(0);

     }
     if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
         readyTofire = false;
         if(bullet.y <= -5){
             bullet = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
             shot = false;
             readyTofire = true;

         }
     }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

//shot of bullet
public void shoot(){

    if(shot){
        bullet.y--;
    }

}

//movement of the oval
public void move(){
    x += xDir;
    y += yDir;
    if(x <= 0){
        x = 0;
    }
    else if(x >= 500){
        x = 500;
    }
    else if(y <= 0){
        y = 0;
    }
    else if(y >= 500){
        y = 500;
    }

}

//thread
public void run() {

    try{
        while(true){
            shoot();
            move();



            Thread.sleep(5);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error!");
    }
}




}
```

Comment: To start with, don't call repaint from within your `paintComponent` method or call `setBackground` or anything else that might call `repaint`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment to have a look at you collision detection statement...

```
if (bullet.intersects(rec));
    g.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);
```

The problem is, you've ended your `if` statement with a `;`

```
if (bullet.intersects(rec));
                           ^---
```

This means that the statement is effectively ignored, it would be the same as...

```
if (bullet.intersects(rec)) {
}
g.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);
```

Which would have alerted you to the problem in the first place

Instead, try using

```
if (bullet.intersects(rec)) {
    g.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);
}
```

Now, don't call `repaint` or any method that might call `repaint` (like `setBackground`) from any `paint` method.  This will set up a cycle of repeated paint events that will eventually consume your CPU.

I don't think you really need 200fps and `Thread.sleep` of roughly 40 would give you 25fps and would typically be more then adequate for your purposes.

You should also consider using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which will allow you to over come the focus related issues of `KeyListener`.

I'd also encourage you to explore the use of a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which will reduce the possibility of un-synchorised updates between the model and the view, which could cause random and difficult to solve artificates or other issues...

**Shooting Problems**

There's a bunch of logic issues and mis-use of variables...

To start with...

- Remove `bx` and `by`, you don't need them.  You actually don't really need `x` and `y` either, but that might be come a little more apparent as we go...
- Don't create `bullet` in `paintComponent`, this is causing some confusion...
- You may not need the `keyReleased` check of `VK_SPACE` but if you did, you should set `shot` to `false` and `bullet` to `null`...
- Setting `readyToFire` to `true` right before you check to see if it's `true` seems weird...however, when you detect a `VK_SPACE` in `keyPressed` check to see if `bullet` is `null` or not, if it's not, then a `bullet` already exist, don't know if this is an issue, but if you were to use a `List`, you could have multiple bullets firing at the same time...any way, create a new `Rectangle` and assign to to `bullet`

```
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    readyTofire = true;
    if (readyTofire) {
        int bx = x + 26;
        int by = y - 15;
        bullet = new Rectangle(bx, by, 5, 3);
        shot = true;
    }
}
```

- In you `shoot` method, do forget to do a bounds check...

```
public void shoot() {

    if (shot) {
        bullet.y--;
        // Have we past the edge of the screen
        if (bullet.y < 0) {
            shot = false;
            bullet = null;
        }
    }

}
```

- And finally, paint it all...Here you should be taking advantage of the 2D Graphics API

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 20, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 55, 55);
    g.fillRect(x + 23, y - 15, 10, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);

    if (shot && bullet != null) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fill(bullet);

        if (bullet.intersects(rec)) {
            g2d.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);
        }
    }
    g2d.dispose();

}
```

And in case I missed anything, here's you the code I tested with...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaGame2 extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {

//variables
    int x, y, xDir, yDir;
    Rectangle bullet;
    boolean readyTofire, shot = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JavaGame2());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

//constructor for game
    public JavaGame2() {

        int x = 150;
        int y = 150;
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        requestFocusInWindow();

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

//drawings
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 20, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 55, 55);
        g.fillRect(x + 23, y - 15, 10, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);

        if (shot && bullet != null) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fill(bullet);

            if (bullet.intersects(rec)) {
                g2d.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();

    }

    public void setxDir(int xdir) {
        xDir = xdir;
    }

    public void setyDir(int ydir) {
        yDir = ydir;
    }

//key event listener keypressed
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            setyDir(-1);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            setyDir(+1);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            setxDir(-1);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            setxDir(+1);

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            readyTofire = true;
            if (readyTofire) {
                int bx = x + 26;
                int by = y - 15;
                bullet = new Rectangle(bx, by, 5, 3);
                shot = true;
            }
        }
    }

//key event listener for key released
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            setyDir(0);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            setyDir(0);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            setxDir(0);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            setxDir(0);

        }
//        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
//            readyTofire = false;
//            if (bullet.y <= -5) {
//                bullet = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
//                shot = false;
//                readyTofire = true;
//
//            }
//        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

//shot of bullet
    public void shoot() {

        if (shot) {
            bullet.y--;
            if (bullet.y < 0) {
                shot = false;
                bullet = null;
            }
        }

    }

//movement of the oval
    public void move() {
        x += xDir;
        y += yDir;
        if (x <= 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x >= 500) {
            x = 500;
        } else if (y <= 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y >= 500) {
            y = 500;
        }

    }

//thread
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                shoot();
                move();
                repaint();

                Thread.sleep(40);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error!");
        }
    }

}
```

No offense, but you approach is a little primitive.  Instead of containing the entire game model within the same class that is trying to display it, you should separate your game "logic" into a model and update the model state and then simply have your view paint the model...IMHO

Comment: but it wont move if I remove repaint()?

Comment: @Renboy You should be calling repaint in your `run` method.  The way you have it now, it's probably updating roughly every millisecond or so, give it a minute or two and your UI will be unusable...

Comment: I replaced ; with {} but still no luck. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Renboy Did you place the `g.drawString("collision!", 50, 20);` within the `{ }` braces?

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I will study and understand your version.